# What's the explanation of the output of this code?

Tags: c++

I didn't understand all of the output of the following code, i tried following a certain logic but still couldn't understand that output

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {

public:
    X() { cout << "cons" << endl; }
    ~X() { cout << "decons" << endl; }

};

X* fun(X o)
{
    X* xo = new X(o);
    return xo;

}

X fun1(X const& o)
{
    X oo;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    X o;
    X* xo = fun(o);
    delete xo;
    o = fun1(o);

    return 0;
}
```

the output is :

```
cons
decons
decons
cons
decons
decons
decons
```

i understood the first line only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `X` is constructed with no arguments, it emits `cons`, but when it's constructed as a copy of another `X`, then it doesn't emit anything.

```
X(const X&) {cout << "copy-cons"<< endl;}
```

Will add a lot of insight about the mystery Xs being destructed.

Here's your code with those points clearly labeled:

```
X* fun(X o) //copy-cons foo-o-param
{
    X* xo = new X(o); //copy-cons fun-xo
    return xo;
} //decons foo-o-param

X fun1(X const& o)
{
    X oo; //cons fun1-oo
    return o; //MAYBE copy-cons fun1-o-return
} //decons fun1-oo

int main()
{
    X o; //cons main-o
    X* xo = fun(o);
    delete xo; //decons main-xo
    o = fun1(o); //copy-assign, then MAYBE decons fun1-o-return
    return 0;
} //decons main-o
```

And those are associated with this purely-theoretical explanatory output

```
cons main-o
copy-cons foo-o-param
copy-cons fun-xo
decons fun-o-param
decons main-xo
cons fun1-oo
copy-cons fun1-return
decons fun1-oo
   (not logged, but copy-assign happens here)
decons fun1-return
decons main-o
```

Comment: may i know when and why are those decons are emited? i know that delete xo; will emit a decons by the way

Comment: I've added details about when each line is emitted.

Comment: @Vergil_The_Killer because an object of class X is being destroyed according to its lifespan

Comment: @MooingDuck wait  a minute please, if an object is called but not returned in a function, does it get destroyed?

Comment: @Vergil_The_Killer: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You mean like `oo` in `fun1`? That object has "automatic" scope, so is destroyed at the end of the `{}` scope that it was declared inside, which in this case is the end of the function.

Comment: I've relabeled the constructors and destructors, and showed theoretical explanatory output.